# Calculate reputation by tag and action

Tags: feature-request

Is there a way to calculate reputation by tag and action (question or answer)?

It would be great to see a matrix like:

```
Tag                         A     Q
---                     ----- -----
crystal-reports         10000    10
  crystal-reports-10     4000     0
objective-c                 0   100
```

While I realize that questions may have more than one tag, I think the relative value would still be helpful.  Moreover, version-specific tags (e.g. crystal-reports-10) could be aggregated (assuming that there is a tag hierarchy) with its parent.

Comment: Uh… Why do we need this?

Comment: Inquiring minds want to know.

Comment: The profile tag summary already sort of does this... albeit not in the neat matrix form you want.

Comment: You have to combine [this](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/217231) with [this](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/203302/user-reputation-history?uid=447356#)